# Is it safe to use a 2 burner reversible griddle on an electric stove?

Tags: stove

I want to use the reversible 2 burner griddle pan on an electric stove. But the rims fit flush on the stove and the elements are hitting the grill. No air can go underneath it or the heat from the burners cannot escape. So I Hav'nt used it yet as I think it might not be safe. Did anybody use their griddle on the electric stove when the rims are flush on the stove?

Comment: I think it would be safe.

Comment: Generally with an electric stove the pot/pan/whatever needs to make as much contact with the burner as possible in order to heat properly.  If you have the griddle floating above the burners and not touching, it will never heat up enough to cook on.

Comment: Is the griddle pan part of your original stove equipment? Or something you added?

Comment: Assuming something like this: https://www.amazon.ca/Lodge-LDP3-Double-Reversible-Griddle/dp/B002CMLTXG Are you suggesting that there is contact between BOTH the element and the griddle pan as well as the rim around the edge and part of your stove that surrounds the elements? What kind of stove do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that this setup is not causing a safety issue.  Since you are not using a gas grill, there is actually less to worry about with it being flush, as there is no burner to potentially snuff out, which would cause a gas buildup.  Also, Lodge's website [states](http://shop.lodgemfg.com/griddles-and-grill-pans/double-play-reversible-grill-griddle.asp) under the **Use And Care** tab that their reversible griddles are good for any stove type, and do not have warnings against using it in such a manner, you should be fine.

From my experience, these are perfectly safe, although you will want to make sure that you have your heating coils (if you have them) flat and flush with the burner trays, so that you achieve optimal heating and ease of use.